# Strange characters returned when using twitter api

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm querying the twitter api using the abraham library and the bio of a user is written in arabic but displays like this:

Ø§Ù†Ø§ Ø²Ù‡Ù‚Øª!

How to encode this or display the correct characters?

Thanks!

```
$twitterOAuth = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
        $_SESSION['access_token'], $_SESSION['access_token_secret']);


$user = $twitterOAuth->get('account/verify_credentials');
$user->description;
```

Comment: Please some of your code, so we can help you. (Btw it looks like your data should be in the UTF-8 format for input & output.

Comment: $twitterOAuth->get('account/verify_credentials');$user->description;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `utf8_encode()` method!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php